# WSO2 API Manager(wso2am-2.1.0) - How to Add Azure AD as an Identity Provider in wso2am-2.1.0?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I'm using wso2am-2.1.0 and I'm hoping to add Azure AD as an Identity Provider using the management console?

However, I am yet to find a proper documentation for reference, except for the following related to the Identity Server, where a separate connector is used.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ISCONNECTORS/Configuring+Microsoft+Azure+AD+Outbound+Provisioning+Connector

Is it possible to add Azure AD as an IdP in wso2am-2.1.0? If it is, is there a proper documentation for reference or is the above documentation valid for APIM as well?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may find this blog article that explains how Azure AD can be used as a federated IdP with APIM useful: https://athiththan11.medium.com/wso2-api-manager-azure-ad-oidc-sso-82a8126c6446

Comment: Hi, I think this article is related to the latest version of APIM.